# Ubuntu 14.04. LTS Crashes

Tags: crash

I ran a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 on my computer and for some reason it occasionally crashes. Not a 100% sure what's causing it.

My computer is a HP Pavilion P6-2220t Desktop.
It has a 6th generation Pentium processor 2.80 Ghz, 500GB hard drive, 4GB Ram.

Comment: What do you mean by crashing?

Comment: I mean the screen freezes, nothing moves, no key commands work, try launching the terminal, go into the dash, etc. Nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was something I did with Steam, I installed some bad unreliable packages while trying to make Steam open.